# c++ creating an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
enum ShapeType
{
    RECTANGLE = 1,
    CIRCLE,
    TRIANGLE,
    MAX
};

int main()
{

    int n;

    std::cout << "Number of elements : ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector <Shape *> shapes;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "What shape do you want to build \n 1) Rectangle\n 2) Circle\n 3) Triangle\n" << std::endl;

        int t;
        // de implementat do while

        std::cin >> t;

        for(ShapeType i = RECTANGLE; i < MAX; i = static_cast<ShapeType>(i+1))
        {
            do
            {
                switch (t)
                {
                case RECTANGLE:
                {
                    int width, height;

                    std::cout << "Width = "; cin >> width;
                    std::cout << "Height = "; cin >> height;

                    Shape *rect = new Rectangle(width, height);
                    shapes.push_back(rect);

                    std::cout << "Rectangle area is: " << rect->getArea() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Rectangle perimeter is: " << rect->getPerimeter() << std::endl;
                    rect->draw();

                    break;
                }
                case CIRCLE:
                {
                    double radius;

                    std::cout << "Please give circle radius: "; std::cin >> radius;

                    Shape *circ = new Circle(radius);
                    shapes.push_back(circ);

                    break;
                }
                case TRIANGLE:
                {
                    double l1, l2 ,l3;

                    std::cout << "Side 1: "; std::cin >> l1;
                    std::cout << "Side 2: "; std::cin >> l2;
                    std::cout << "Side 3: "; std::cin >> l3;

                    Shape *tri = new Triangle(l1, l2, l3);
                    shapes.push_back(tri);

                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(n > i);
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have here an abstract Shape class and Rectangle, Circle and Triangle that inherit it. I wish to introduce 'n' number of shapes and do a loop for them.
For example i choose i want to make 3 shapes, the option to choose them appears, choose a shape then all over again 3 times. I have an assignment with this and i have to use do while. I had some cheap attempts but I'm lost. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a quick explaination how you can do it.

```
int n,i=0;  
    cout << "Enter no of elements";
    cin >> n;

    if( n > 0 ){
        do{
            int shapeType;
            cout << "choose type";
            cin >> shapeType;
            switch(shapeType){
                case RECTANGLE:
                    break;
                case CIRCLE:
                    break;
                ...
            }
            ++i;
        }while(i<n);
    }
```

Comment: change to `}while(i<n);`

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the index `i` in the inner loop causing the outer loop to misbehave. Change it to another variable such as `j` and change the relevant uses of this variable.

Comment: Also, if you change the inner index variable,  `while(n > i);{break;}` is irrelevant as `i` can't be high than `n` (see the condition in the outer loop)

Comment: I saw the flaw with the same index name, changed it. But still gives the same case in a loop. How do i make the loop to allow me to create other shapes depending on the number of elements i've chosen. For now if i choose 5 elements and choose first Circle, it gives me the Circle case in infinite loop.

Comment: That's because `n>i` in the `do..while` loop is always true. You initialize `i` to be smaller than `n` and `i` can never be larger than `n`.